# how to add the value of columns in prolog ?

Tags: prolog, sum

i have the following rules:

```
seller(peter,20).    
seller(jose,45).    
...............    
seller(mary,67).
```

I want to get the total value of the sellings, it would be 20+45+....+67.

How can i do that?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you attempted anything?

Comment: i have attempted a lot of things, i´m new with it and it`s very difficult for me. I will try now with the new information. I found a lot of information about how to add with list, but not with columns. THanks.

Comment: It would probably be good if you showed what you think is your most promising attempt and folks here could help you with it. On stackoverflow.com, it's usually not a good idea to have a question that is "here's my problem; solve it for me", although it sometimes does get solutions, but will also often get down-voted for lack of show of effort.

Comment: @lurker: you're partially right, but OP'perplexity is full justified, because aggregation (or better, idiomatic aggregation, like that expressed by people accustomed to SQL) is a difficult theme in Prolog

Comment: @CapelliC, yes, I see your point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

library([aggregate](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=aggregate)), where not available, can be replaced by an [all solutions](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=allsolutions) builtin, like findall/3

```
sum_column_of(Pred, Col, Sum) :-
  arg(Col, Pred, ColValue),
  findall(ColValue, call(Pred), Values),
  sum_list(Values, Sum).
```

usage:

```
?- sum_column_of(seller(_,_), 2, T).
T = 132.
```

note the binding of ColValue is done once, *before* actual predicates are inquired.
We could extend this pattern - with ingenuity - to perform
further filtering and projection.

Comment: I like the binding of `ColValue`, quite nifty!

Comment: The better thing imho is that Pred can be a general callable, with arguments placed in structured domain. Not apparent from the question...

Answer (score 0):

#### Basics

Basic summation of numbers:

```
?- X is 20 + 45 + 67.
X = 132.
```

#### Slightly more advanced

If you have very many `seller/2` facts or these facts are asserted dynamically, you do not want to enter all numbers by hand. Instead, you want the arguments to be added algorithmically:

```
?- use_module(library(aggregate)).
?- aggregate_all(sum(Age), seller(_, Age), SummedAge).
SummedAge = 132.
```

#### Others

There are many other ways in which this can be done as well. E.g., there is `plus/3` which has multiple modes.